# Сумма каждых 3-х элементов numpy массива

Tags: python, numpy

Есть numpy массив. В реальности он гораздо больше:

```
arr = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 1]
```

Задача посчитать сумму каждых трех элементов, пример:

```
1+0+1=2
0+1+0=1
1+0+0=1
0+0+2=2
0+2+0=2
2+0+3=5
0+3+1=4

new_arr = [2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 4]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужна [одномерная свёртка](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html):

```
new_arr = np.convolve(arr, [1, 1, 1], 'valid')
```

https://ideone.com/fZWjYB

Answer (score 1):

У вас обычный массив питона. Просто итерируетесь параллельно с помощью `zip` по массиву со сдвигами 0, 1 и 2, и берёте сумму на каждой итерации:

```
arr = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 1]
print(list(map(sum, zip(arr, arr[1:], arr[2:]))))

# [2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 4]
```

Или вот вариант всё же с использованием `Numpy`, просто складываете массивы, опять же со сдвигом, но в отличие от варианта с использованием `zip` (который смотрит на размер наименьшего массива), тут массивы надо выровнять по размеру, поэтому срезы нужны более точные:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 1])
print(arr[:-2] + arr[1:-1] + arr[2:])

# array([2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 4])
```

Comment: Способом с zip'ом даже быстрее по всей видимости)

Answer (score 1):

Для целых чисел, чтобы не пересчитывать суммы, можно сделать так:

```
arr = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 1]
s = sum(arr[:3])
print(s, end =  " ")
for i in range(3, len(arr)):
    s += arr[i]-arr[i-3]
    print(s, end =  " ")

2 1 1 2 2 5 4
```